# Is there a way to decompile the dynamic proxy classes that are generated by NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I really like to know what's going on in the dynamic proxy classes that NHibernate generates.

I'm quite aware of what NHibernate dynamic proxies do on a higher level but it could definitely come in handy to be able to decompile them (using Reflector or something alike) during debugging sessions.

So, is there a way to decompile the dynamic proxy classes that are generated by NHibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using NHibernate 3.2.0 (older version don't generate the proxies themself). Just recompile the NHibernate source with the DEBUG and DEBUG_PROXY_OUTPUT compilation symbols. NHibernate will then write the module (*.mod) and assembly (generatedAssembly.dll) files to the current directory when a proxy type is created.

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. I had to set a break point in the NHibernate proxy factory class (where the .dll is written) to find out the directory it was written to (C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0).

Answer (score 1):

Just take the assembly the classes reside in and open it with [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).
In the case of dynamically generated proxies:
The also reside in an assembly. You could put some code into your program that identifies the assembly in which the generated proxy classes reside and dump it to the disk and then open it in ILSpy.

Comment: Are you sure you understand my point? I'm talking about the dynamic proxies NH generates by inheriting from my entities. Obviously, they aren't in a physical assembly file since there is no build time code generation going on.

Comment: @Sandor: Hint for the future: Put all necessary info into your question. You didn't write anything about dynamic proxies.

Comment: Good point. I wasn't really aware of different kinds of proxies being at work here. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I have located the in-memory assembly but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to write it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referering to NHibernate's collection proxy, you could just download NHibernate's source code, 
but if you'r referring to the dynamic proxy's nhibernate generate on runtime than I dont think you can.