# Is there a way to decompile the dynamic proxy classes that are generated by NHibernate 4.0?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, proxy

[This question was already asked here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662694/is-there-a-way-to-decompile-the-dynamic-proxy-classes-that-are-generated-by-nhib)  but the answer refers to NHibernate 3.2.0.

So, is there a way to decompile the dynamic proxy classes that are generated by NHibernate 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

using a custom Proxyfactory should do the trick. Example config using FluentNHibernate

```
var config = Fluently.Configure()
    .ProxyFactoryFactory<MyProxyFactoryFactory>()
```

which uses the classes

```
class MyProxyFactoryFactory : DefaultProxyFactoryFactory, IProxyFactoryFactory
{
    IProxyFactory IProxyFactoryFactory.BuildProxyFactory()
    {
        return new MyProxyFactory();
    }
}

class MyProxyFactory : AbstractProxyFactory, IProxyAssemblyBuilder
{
    const string PathToSave = "D:/";

    private readonly ProxyFactory factory;

    public MyProxyFactory()
    {
        factory = new ProxyFactory(this);
    }

    public override INHibernateProxy GetProxy(object id, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        try
        {
            var initializer = new DefaultLazyInitializer(EntityName, PersistentClass, id, GetIdentifierMethod, SetIdentifierMethod, ComponentIdType, session);

            object proxyInstance = IsClassProxy
                                    ? factory.CreateProxy(PersistentClass, initializer, Interfaces)
                                    : factory.CreateProxy(Interfaces[0], initializer, Interfaces);

            return (INHibernateProxy)proxyInstance;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HibernateException("Creating a proxy instance failed", ex);
        }
    }

    public override object GetFieldInterceptionProxy(object instanceToWrap)
    {
        var interceptor = new DefaultDynamicLazyFieldInterceptor();
        return factory.CreateProxy(PersistentClass, interceptor, new[] { typeof(IFieldInterceptorAccessor) });
    }

    public AssemblyBuilder DefineDynamicAssembly(AppDomain appDomain, AssemblyName name)
    {
        return appDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave, PathToSave);
    }

    public ModuleBuilder DefineDynamicModule(AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder, string moduleName)
    {
        return assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(moduleName, moduleName + ".mod", true);
    }

    public void Save(AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder)
    {
        assemblyBuilder.Save("generatedAssembly.dll");
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an Exception: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder' to type 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder'.

Comment: hmm it worked in a quick test program i wrote for this but does not work anymore when i write it again. I will investigate when i have the time.